# Can I make SML print each recursion?

Tags: sml

I wonder if there is any way that I can make SML print each recursion out? I am having problem with a function I wrote and that would be very helpful!

I am using Emacs if it matters.

Thanks!

Comment: Please, add a part of the code you consider important to the understanding of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have several expressions in a row in sml by putting semicolons between them and surrounding the entire thing with parentheses, like this:

```
(exp1;exp2;exp3)
```

The result of the last expression is the only one that is kept - the others are just thrown away. However, you can have an expression with side effects, such as print, and then the thing you actually want to do after.

```
fun useless x = (print "Hey, there\n";x+2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
fun annotatedFold _ y []        = (print "base case\n"; y)
  | annotatedFold f y (x :: xs) = (print "recursive case\n"; annotatedFold (f x y) xs)
```

(Although, in all honesty, I would try to put the printing logic in `f`, if possible)